# 'not exists' and 'not in', which one has better performance?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select objectid
      ,name
      ,address
 from library_t l 
 where not exists (select *
                     from d107 d 
                    where l.objectid = d.objectid
                   )

select objectid
      ,name
      ,address
  from library_t l 
  where l.objectid not in (select objectid 
                             from d107
                          )
```

If both objectid columns have indexs, which one is better in oracle?

Comment: Apart from speed, you should know that they don't produce the same resultset in every situation. You cannot always use them as substitutes in each scenario.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`.

The execution plans may be the same at the moment but if either column is altered in the future to **allow NULLs** the NOT IN version will need to do more work.

The most important thing to note about NOT EXISTS and NOT IN is that, unlike EXISTS and IN,  they are not equivalent in all cases. Specifically, when NULLs are involved they will return different results. To be totally specific, when the subquery returns even one null, NOT IN will not match any rows.

Answer (score 3):

`[NOT] IN` and `[NOT] EXISTS` operators are processed differently. `[NOT] IN` is processed  more like a join whereas `[NOT] EXISTS` is processed more like a loop with `IF` condition. Choosing one over another, of course, depends on a situation: on volume of data that driven and driving queries return. In the case of `[NOT] IN` operator inner query (`..where id in (select id from table ))` is a driving query whereas in the case of `[NOT] EXISTS` outer query is a driving query. So if the sub-query (inner query) returns small amount of data because of either a table in the sub-query contains small number of rows or there is an intensive filtering applied to the sub-query `[NOT] IN` operator may give better performance. If the sub-query returns large volume of data or the major filtering is happening in outer-query `[NOT] EXISTS` operator is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

Both of them do a subquery.  Faster would be:

```
select lib.objectid, lib.name, lib.address
from library_t lib
     left outer join d107 dd on lib.objectid = dd.objectid
where dd is null
```

Comment: The question was for a SELECT not a DELETE so there was no reason my answer should have been a DELETE.  For a DELETE I would use a subquery `DELETE FROM library_t lib_del WHERE lib_del.objectId in (select lib.objectID from ...)`.  The difference in using a subquery here is that it is not a co-related subquery.  The examples in the question require going through the results of the subquery for what is not in the subquery which the database optimizer might not find an optimal way to do.  With the DELETE above, most likely it will find an optimal way to do the DELETE.

Comment: Yes you are correct, this question is for a select.  I was researching the cleanest way to perform a delete, read several other posts, and was still thinking about my original question when I read your answer.  I have upvoted your answer as I think it is the cleanest and best solution (for both select and delete).  I did apply the left join in my delete query, and after specifying the table name after the DELETE keyword, it worked well, just as left join has worked for many select queries I have written previously.  I have removed my original comment as it is off-topic.