# Filter values based on another column in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table with purchase orders, the orders' lines and a code for each line

| Order_ID | LINE | CODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A0001 | 1 | aaaa |
| A0002 | 1 | bbbb |
| A0002 | 2 | xxxx |
| A0003 | 1 | cccc |
| A0004 | 1 | xxxx |
| A0004 | 2 | dddd |

And I need to filter out all the Orders that have at least one line with the code 'xxxx':

| Order_ID | LINE | CODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A0001 | 1 | aaaa |
| A0003 | 1 | cccc |

I thought something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE Order_ID not in (SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CODE = 'xxxx')
```

BUT, the big problem here is that I'm working with a pretty big query so the subquery is also too large and the whole query takes a lot to run. Is there any workaround to avoid the subquery?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['not exists' and 'not in', which one has better performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997386/not-exists-and-not-in-which-one-has-better-performance)

Comment: your subquery is wrong as it should be `SELECT Order_ID  FROM MyTable WHERE CODE = 'xxxxx'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond the issue others have pointed out with your syntax, the big problem is the subquery being called for each row.  I've done a test on a similar big table with a non-unique field (like your `Order_ID`), and found very large savings by structuring the query with a CTE:

```
WITH bad_ids AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT Order_ID
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE CODE = 'xxxx'
)

SELECT *
FROM MyTable m
LEFT JOIN bad_ids b
  ON m.Order_ID = b.Order_ID
WHERE b.Order_ID IS NULL;
```

Here I'm assuming `Order_ID` is not allowed to be null.

Given the huge difference I saw in performance, I'd be surprised if you didn't see the same, no matter what the differences are between query planners.

**Edit**: Essentially this works because the above query is searching through the table twice and joining once.  Your query is searching some subset of the table as many times as you have rows.

Answer (score 1):

The column `Order_ID` should be compared with itself, not with any column (`*`):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE Order_ID not in (SELECT Order_ID FROM MyTable WHERE CODE = 'xxxx')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE CODE <> 'xxxx'
```

Comment: This won't do what Scot is asking.  In the sample data provided, we want to remove `Order_ID`s A0002 and A0004 completely, since there are rows with these IDs and `CODE = 'xxxx'`.  Your query only removes the specific rows with `CODE = 'xxxx'`